# extrapolate word from TextView by location

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextview

I have a TextView and I need to insert a word in a string from the location. Use this method to derive the location

```
NSInteger location = textView.selectedRange.location;
```

But I do not know how to put this into a string.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the selection with a word, the simplest would be something like this:

```
NSRange range = textView.selectedRange;
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSString *replacement = @"some word";
    textView.text = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                           withString:replacement];
}
```

For an empty selection, this would insert the text at the caret position, if text is selected, it would be replaced. On iOS 5, using the methods in the `UITextInput` protocol would probably be more efficient, but also more cumbersome to use.

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you looking for?

```
NSInteger location = textView.selectedRange.location;
UITextView yourTxtView;
yourTxtView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",location];
```